# Potentials with continuous spectra except for discrete set of values

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

Section 18 of Landau & Lifschitz's Quantum Mechanics discusses how the Schrödinger equation with a potential that vanishes at spatial infinity can have a continuous spectrum, a discrete spectrum, or both. They then mention in a footnote that "for some forms of [the potential] (which have no physical significance), a discrete set of values may be missing from the otherwise continuous spectrum."

I thought this was interesting. Question: What is an example of such a potential?

Comment: It is funny that in the German edition of the textbook, the relevant footnote differs quite  substantially from the one given in the English edition. The German version (translated into English) reads:  "... that for some particular types of functions $U(x,y,z)$ (having no physical relevance) a discrete set of values can be PRESENT in the continuous spectrum". I do not know the original text in the original Russian edition, but the German version does make more sense to me. It can indeed happen that discrete eigenvalues of certain selfadjoint operators are embedded in the continuous spectrum.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/737976/82615) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/192290), though it's not clear if the answers there address the quote, and something far simpler was likely intended in the original quote.